# Delay painting in Qt

Tags: qt, real-time, paint

I'm building a real-time system in Qt. Every 20 ms I need to paint 5 points in a `QFrame` to make the painting of a signal looks like real time. When I only paint the signal in the QFrame, the call to `paintEvent()` is done with the desired frequency, 20 ms. But when I focus on another QWidget or when I show another window (in other words, when I perform another painting action that isn’t very simple) the call to `paintEvent()` starts to slow down and the samples of the signal are accumulated.

The call to the function `paintEvent()` is made from the call to the function `update()` of the `QFrame` every 20 ms. In Qt you cannot separate the painted gui into threads. Therefore, the call to `paintEvent()` runs in the same thread as the call to the functions responsible for the other actions of painting in the gui. This causes that when focusing another `QWidget`, when the processing associated with painting a box in the `QWidget` is delayed, the event of painting the signal is delayed.

The question is whether there is any way to make the event to paint signal priority, so that `paintEvent()` is called with the same frequency, no matter what it is done in the gui. I use repaint instead of update, because in the help of Qt it says that repaint makes the direct call to `paintEvent()`, but the result was disastrous.

Any other idea will be of great help.

Comment: I assume you use a `QTimer ` with an interval of 20. To be honest, 20ms is way too frequent of a call. Any chance of increasing that interval to say, 50 ms?

Comment: Also, I personally noticed a performance drop when I switched from Qt4 to Qt5 `QWidget` app that is based on `paintEvent()`. What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: I cannot use a longer time interval. that is the time that makes the painted signal look like in real time

Comment: I am using qt4 now.

Comment: The problem is that every 4 ms I get a sample. every 20 ms I paint 5 and the painting looks in real time. But if I paint 10 samples, which are 40 ms the blocks of points are very large and looks bad. This app is for a patient monitor.

Comment: It difficult to give precise answer mainly as you didn't share your code, you might review [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think [`QCoreApplication::processEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) could be a solution

Comment: This is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please describe your `X` problem. What are you painting, what kind of data. How often data are refreshed and how they should be accumulated? If you explain this than it will turn out that painting problem is a secondary issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll try to formulate the question in the most explanatory way possible, including code. the problem is that it's a very big project and to create an example that represents what is happening is a little complex, but I'll try.

Comment: @BastianChivas That is often the case. The best you can maybe do is to explain what kind of data you are painting with on both paintEvents. And elaborate your architecture if there is more.